# Rails 4 tagging in place editing

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, tagging, acts-as-taggable-on, best-in-place

I'm looking for way to implement a tagging system similar to the one in stackoverflow i.e. type a word into a text field hit enter and the tag is saved and do this multiple times. Currently I'm using the best_in_place gem and I have a working version where I can edit a single tag.

Is there way to use best_in_place to do this or is there a better way, for example using act_as_taggable and some jquery?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have done what you say but using [select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#tags), it has support for multipple tags, you can set a delimiter character like a `,` and every time you hit enter the tag is added.

You can add the js and css files to the rails project or simple add the [select2 gem](https://github.com/argerim/select2-rails) to your Gemfile.